# How do you return a dataframe featuring the specific date on which a min or max value occurred?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `all_data` featuring the average values of black carbon concentration for each month of the year for 5 years. The dataframe indices are the last day of each month (yyyy-mm-dd). I want to resample the data by year and build a new dataframe with the minimum values for each year (not month). This is what I did:

```
all_data.resample('1Y').min()
```

However, this returns a dataframe with the last month of every year and I want to the specific month that the minimum value occurred. I'm not sure if there are any good tips out there.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a year column from the index and group by it, and then get the first value for each sorted group with nth (uses a zero-based index).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

bc = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=60)
idx = pd.date_range("2016-01-31", periods=60, freq="M")
df = pd.DataFrame({'bc': bc}, index=idx)

df['year'] = df.index.year

(
  df
  .sort_values(['bc'])
  .groupby(df['year'], as_index=False)
  .nth(0)
)
```

Output

```
            bc  year
2016-07-31   1  2016
2019-05-31   3  2019
2018-11-30   4  2018
2020-10-31   5  2020
2017-03-31   9  2017
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you want to get the minimum value appeared on column `col`:

```py
all_data.loc[all_data['col'].isin(all_data.resample('1Y').min()['col'])]
```